# Create a column with a function which variables come from other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have df with two columns of date: `Start` and `End` columns. I have a function which can calculate business days between two dates (and doing other stuff). `bday_special(start, end)`! **And End value has to not be empty (NaT) else we put 0 in Delay.**

I need to create a third column with the result of the two passed in the function.

I was used to do:

```
df['Delay'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End']) - pd.to_datetime(df['Start'])
```

Now I just need something like that :

```
df["Delay"] = df[df["End"]!=np.NaT].apply(bday_special(df["Start"], df["End"]))

df["Delay"] = df.apply(lambda df: if df["End"] is not np.NaT , bday_special(df["Start"], df["End"]), else 0)
```

> TypeError: Cannot convert input

Both above doesn't work... What is the appropriate syntax please?

I prefer to stick with pandas scheme instead of going throug lists

Comment: Doesn't https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65099853/creating-if-statement-for-column-based-on-nan/65100018#65100018 answer your question?

Comment: I'm not sure to get it, I need the columns of the dataframe as arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `apply` with the `axis=1` parameter

```
df["Delay"] = df.apply(lambda x: 0 if x.End is np.nan else bday_special(x.Start, x.End), axis=1) # axis=1 means iterate over rows
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. However, I have this error 
`AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'NaT'` I will use `pd.NaT`

Comment: We used `apply` and not `lapply` here, right ?